# css transform specified by class

Tags: css, modularity

I am looking for a way in vanilla css or css preprocessor such that

> When `class1` and `class2` both have a `transform` property defined, a single html element of `class1` and `class2` has both transformations applied.

That is to say, I am looking for a way such that a class is only controlling one set of transformations. Right now it appears the last class defined in the css file has its transformation(s) displayed. I am not familiar with css preprocessors so if one of them has this feature please also link to a post/article/reply that summarizes what the preprocessor could do in general.

I am aware of methods of introducing wrapper html elements, one for each set of transformations, and using `+=` in js. But I'm specifically looking for a css solution. I am open to altering html if it's just going to be a fixed number of elements regardless of the number of transformations.

```css
.scale {
  transform: scale(0.8) rotate(4deg);
}

.translate {
  transform: translate(20px);
}

div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<div class="scale">text</div>
<div class="translate">text</div>
<div class="scale translate">text</div>
<div class="translate scale">text</div>
```

I know that order matters in transformations. But I am not concerned about that at the moment. I just want to know if there there exists a way to modify instead of overwrite a rule.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm fully understanding. Is there any reason not to define .class1.class2 {transform: the transform values here;}

Comment: @AHaworth I just want `transform1` and `transform2` classes. Instead of a third class `transform1-and-2`, i want simply the 2 classes to be controlled separately, and by having both classes, the element does both transformations ... unless Im misunderstanding the .class1.class2 selector?

Comment: I definitely am a bit confused! I wasn't suggesting you create a third class, just put .class1.class2 into the stylesheet as well as the other two.

Comment: You will need to create a third class for this, for the exact reason you see - the last CSS rule that uses `transform` will override everything before it. You want scale and translate to apply to an element - so you'll need a class that does both. A preprocessor won't help you, since it compiles to CSS. A preprocessor will only help you write a `function` or `mixin` that handles the math to create all the rules instead of you having to handwrite them all.

Comment: @AHaworth oh I see! it just doesn't scale nicely when there are say 5 transformations and i'd have to do that 31 times for all combinations.

Comment: Correct - scaling is a pain. I think I'd knock up a special 'pre processor' to do this (a little JS). But there's a further wrinkle, what is the priority to be if there are two translateYs for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

```
* {
    /* space before semicolon is essential
       to make it a valid empty value */
    --scale: ;
    --translate: ;
}

.scale {
    --scale: scale(0.8) rotate(4deg);
}

.translate {
    --translate: translate(20px);
}

.scale,
.translate {
    transform: var(--scale) var(--translate);
}
```